# Adding new field in sales_flat_order_item table from custom module in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

In magento i created a custom module and completed the template and controller part, but confused about handling the model and db part. From my custom module i want to alter the table **sales_flat_order_item** and add an additional field. Now i created a set up script like

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
ALTER TABLE sales_flat_order_item ADD COLUMN new_field TEXT NULL;

ALTER TABLE sales_flat_invoice_item ADD COLUMN new_field TEXT NULL;

ALTER TABLE sales_flat_shipment_item ADD COLUMN new_field TEXT NULL;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

in path 
app\code\local\Namespace\Module\sql\_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
But the table is not seems to be altered what configuration can be done in the script or module files to add the additional field and processing data with the same like the other fields. any one help. Thanks.

Comment: What version of magento are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your config.xml configuration looks like?

under `<global></global>` tag you need to add:

```
<resources>
    <sql_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Namespace_Module</module>
        </setup>
    </sql_setup>
</resources>
```

Comment: Sorry to say, Added this in config files but no result.

Comment: can you post all of your config.xml file? also please check your database: select * from core_resource where code like 'sql_setup';

Comment: The given query returns one row, with code: sql_setup, version: 0.4.0,data_version: 0.4.0

Comment: It means your current modules's version is 0.4.0.
You can do upgrade but not install.
If you're going to do install, you need to delete the value in core_resource (delete from core_resource where code like 'sql_setup') and change your module's version into 0.1.0 (<version>0.1.0</version>)

Comment: Create file under sql_setup, eg: mysql4-upgrade-0.4.0-0.5.0.php and then you need to change your module's version into 0.5.0. That means you're upgrading it from version 0.4.0 into version 0.5.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14615/discussion-between-soji-and-ivantedja)

Answer (score 0):

try to put something like this

```
 $installer->run("
ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('sales_flat_shipment_item')} ADD `new_field` TEXT NULL ;
");
```

Comment: Tried this but not worked for me. Is there any changes needed in model files or config xml? any idea?

Comment: Yes the version value is changed.